# ng2-ckeditor "CKEDITOR" not defined

Tags: typescript, angular, ckeditor

I have done the following steps:

1. Install ng2-ckeditor
   -JSPM : jspm install ng2-ckeditor=github:chymz/ng2-ckeditor
   -NPM : npm install ng2-ckeditor
2. create ts file:

   ```
   import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
   import {CKEditor} from 'ng2-ckeditor';

   @Component({
     selector: 'sample',
     directives: [CKEditor],
     template: `
       <ckeditor [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent" [config]="{uiColor: '#99000'}"></ckeditor>`
   })
   export class Sample{
     constructor(){
       this.ckeditorContent = `<p>My HTML</p>`;
     }
   }
   ```

But in runtime I got an exception **"CKEDITOR is not defined".**

I tried to import the "**ckeditor**" itself,
but in this case i got another runtime exception 
**"ckeditor uncaught typeerror cannot set property 'dir' of undefined**"

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a step. You need to include a link to an actual CKEditor source file in your HTML. Go [here](http://ckeditor.com/download) and select a version. Include it like so:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.8/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

The remaining steps are as you outlined.

**Edit**

In case you didn't set up SystemJS properly is should look something like this:

```
System.config({
        packages: {
            "app": {
                "format": 'register',
                "defaultExtension": 'js'
            },
            "ng2-ckeditor": {
                "defaultExtension": "js"
            }
        },
        map: {
            "ng2-ckeditor": "node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/lib/CKEditor.js"
        }
    });
```

Comment: same question. what is the ocation for system file

Comment: @AayushiGupta System.js is no longer used. You can go here for details however: https://scotch.io/courses/getting-started-with-angular-2/systemjs.